# BibTex: citation in an Enumerate is backref'ed with index, not page number

Tags: bibtex, lists, enumerate, back-referencing

I have the following text:

> \begin{enumerate}
>   \item bla
>   \item blabla
>   \item Quando o material termoplástico resfria, este endurece, desenvolvendo aderência entre o aço e o concreto, agora comprimido. \cite{Leonhardt}
>   \end{enumerate}

This section happens in what ends up being page 12. Now, when the bibliography is presented, it comes out as:

[image: LEONHARDT, F. Prestressed concrete design and construction. Berlin-Wilmersdorf, Alemanha: Verlag von Wilhelm Ernst & Sohn, 1964. Traduzido por C. van Amerongen. 3]

Where that `3` is obviously the backref to the citation. This is the index of the enumerate item (if I move the citation to the second item, it becomes a 2, for example).

How does one make the backref return the page number?

Comment: Is the citing inside the item changing the content of the bibliography? Are you running `bibtex`?

Comment: I am running bibtex, yes. And no, the item is not changing the content. The item is all pure text ending with the \cite. I've edited the OP with precisely what I have for that item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `backref` option to `hyperref` can take a value.  By default it is `section`, but this does not seem to be giving the correct output, as it picks up the item number instead inside an enumerate.  On the other hand you are requesting a page ref, and passing the `page` option does work:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item A
\item B
\item C~\cite{art}
\end{enumerate}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

with `test.bib`

```
@Article{art,
  author =   {Author, A. N.},
  title =    {On\dots},
  journal =  {J. Jour.},
  year =     2004
}
```